# Table Manipulation in SQL

Tags: mysql

The table I have right now is this:
[image]

Is there a way in MySQL to manipulate and spread the table  to:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 0):

This is called `records to columns conversion` or `pivot`. 
The general query structure is, done with a `GROUP BY` , `CASE END` and some aggregate function like `MAX`, `MIN` or `SUM`. In MySQL/MariaDB or anny database system which does not have a `PIVOT()` kind of function 
Where `MAX()` and `MIN()` can pivot every datatype, `SUM()` is only suitable for numeric datatypes.

```
SELECT 
   Name
 , SUM(CASE WHEN Cycle = 'weekly' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS weekly
 ..
 ..
FROM
 t
GROUP BY 
 Name
```

Note because SQL tables when stored and selections off SQL tables are by SQL definition **orderless** so the result off this query is **nondeterministic (random)**, there wasn't anny column in your data example which could be used to make a deterministic (fixed) order by